# How does C treat char sums?

Tags: c++, c, char, int

When I'm in C++, and I call an overloaded function foo, like so:

```
foo('e' - (char) 5)
```

it can output "this is a char" or "this is an int" based on the type result. I get "this is an int" from my program, like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(char x)
{
    std::cout << "output is a char" << std::endl;
}
void foo(int x)
{
    std::cout << "output is an int" << std::endl;
}
int main()
{
    foo('a' + (char) 5);
}
```

My instructor says that in C, the expression above, `('a' + (char) 5)`, evaluates as a char. I see in the C99 standard that chars are promoted to ints to find the sum, but does C recast them back to chars when it's done? I can't find any references that seem credible saying one way or another what C actually does after the promotion is completed, and the sum is found.

Is the sum left as an int, or given as a char? How can I prove this in C, or is there a reference I'm not understanding/finding?

Comment: Hence, prove your instructor wrong by citing the standard an providing the test!

Comment: It depends on who/what is using the sum. In C, LHS determines the type. In Matlab, if you assign a `int` to a `double`, then the `double` variable is changed to `int`. However, in C, `int` is converted to `double` and the `double` variable never changes its type. So, what the sum is cast to depends on its usage.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag because C++ has a section that C is missing titled "built-in operators" that provides the result type and the question seems to be about C specifically.

Comment: @chris , now there's a `<iostream>` and `cout` in a question tagged C

Comment: @ArunA.S and function overloading.....

Comment: I provided the test, his rebuttal was that it's C++, not C. I know not how to prove it in C.

Comment: @ArunA.S I think that's okay.  The question is actually about C, even though it uses C++ code as examples/comparison.

Comment: @ArunA.S, I know, it's not an easy decision, but the OP looks like he wants a C answer, and the C++ looks to be there as an assumption that C and C++ have the same answer. This is harder to test in C for the OP. My main reason for removing it was to keep the C++ answers away.

Comment: @ArunA.S That's why I originally included the tag. Thought it would be weird not to, even though the question is about C.

Comment: I do know the answer is different for C and C++. If I thought they were the same, I would already have my answer based on my program.

Comment: You could print the `sizeof` the expression to tell whether it's char or int in C.

Comment: C code that shows that GCC treats the result as an `int`.
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00517f62c60323dd

Comment: Just a note I haven't come across while reading the answers diagonally: in C, `'a'` is a value of type `int`.

Comment: @pmg, do you have a reference for that? I'd love to include it in my response to him, as he used such an example in his response to my evaluation of the question stated above.

Comment: @pmg That's true, but it doesn't really affect the answer. `(char)'a' + (char)5` is still an `int` and for the same reason.

Comment: @MagnaVis Added that reference to my answer, as per pmg's comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C Standard, 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions, emphasis mine:

> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. **Unless
>   explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of
>   the result**, whose type domain is the type domain of the operands if they are the same,
>   and complex otherwise. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*:
>
> - First, if the correspeonding real type of either operand is `long double`...
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`...
> - Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`...
> - Otherwise, **the integer promotions are performed on both operands**. Then the following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
>
>   - If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.

So you are exactly correct. The type of the expression `'a' + (char) 5` is `int`. There is no recasting back to `char`, unless explicitly asked for by the user. Note that `'a'` here has type `int`, so it's only the `(char)5` that needs to be promoted. This is stipulated in 6.4.4.4 Character Constants:

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
>   in single-quotes, as in `'x'`.
>   ...
>   An integer character constant has type `int`.

There is an example demonstrating the explicit recasting to `char`:

> In executing the fragment
>
> ```
> char c1, c2;
> /* ... */
> c1 = c1 + c2
> ```
>
> the ‘‘integer promotions’’ require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to `int` size and then add the two `int`s and truncate the sum. Provided the addition of two `char`s can be done without overflow, or with overflow wrapping silently to produce the correct result, the actual execution need only produce the same result, possibly omitting the promotions.

The truncation here only happens because we assign back to a `char`.

Answer (score 3):

Your instructor seems to be wrong. Additional to your standard find that the arithmetic promotes to `int`, we can use a simple test program to show the behavior (no standard prove of course, but the same level of proof as your C++ test):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   printf("%g",'c' - (char)5);
}
```

produces

> Warning: format specifies type 'double' but argument has type 'int'

with [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97380b3907f332c5) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88daee27b5e3fc41).

Answer (score 3):

No, C does not recast them back to chars.

The standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) says (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions):

> Many operators that expect operands of arithmetic type cause conversions and yield result
>   types in a similar way. The purpose is to determine a common real type for the operands
>   and result. For the specified operands, each operand is converted, without change of type
>   domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is the common real type. **Unless**
>   **explicitly stated otherwise, the common real type is also the corresponding real type of**
>   **the result**, whose type domain is determined by the operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can't determine the type of an expression as easily in C, but you can easily determine the size of an expression:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("sizeof(char)==1\n");
    printf("sizeof(int)==%u\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof('a' + (char) 5)==%u\n", sizeof('a' + (char) 5));
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me:

```
sizeof(char)==1
sizeof(int)==4
sizeof('a' + (char) 5)==4
```

which at least proves that `'a' + (char) 5` is *not* of type `char`.

Comment: This is not a reliable solution. It would fail on machines like ones whose `sizeof(int40_t)` and `sizeof(int64_t)` are both `8`, which I work with every day.

Comment: I didn't claim it determined the exact type, just that it ruled out `char`.

Comment: I'm just saying that different types, including `char` and `int`, can have same size, but still be distinct types because of range and overflow behaviour.

Comment: This was extremely helpful as well. I understood that this wasn't proof that it's an int, but it was helpful for me to provide in my response as proof that, at the very least, it's not a char either. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's promoted to an `int`, and there's nothing to tell the compiler it should use anything else. You can convert back to a char like this:

```
foo((char)('a' + 5));
```

This tells the compiler to treat the result of the calculation as a `char`, otherwise it leaves it as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Section 6.5.2.2/6

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on
>   each argument...

So the answer to your question depends on the function prototype. If the function is declared as

```
void foo(int x)
```

or

```
void foo()
```

then the function argument will be passed as an `int`.

OTOH, if the function is declared as

```
void foo( char x )
```

then the result of the expression will be implicitly cast to `char`.

Answer (score 0):

In C (unlike C++), the character literal `'a'` has type `int` (§6.4.4.4¶10: "An integer character constant has type `int`.")

Even if that were not the case, the C standard clearly states that prior to the evaluation of the operator `+`, "[i]f both operands have arithmetic type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on them." (C11, §6.5.6 ¶4) In this respect, C and C++ have identical semantics. (See `[expr.add]` §5.7¶1  of C++)

Answer (score -1):

From the C++ Standard (C++ Working Draft N3797, 5.7 Additive operators)

> 1 The additive operators + and - group left-to-right. **The usual
>   arithmetic conversions are performed for operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type.**

and (5 Expressions)

> 10 Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
>   enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
>   way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
>   the result. This pattern is called the usual arithmetic conversions,
>   which are defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> — Otherwise, **the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on
>   both operands**.62 Then the following rules shall be applied to the
>   promoted operands:

Thus the expression in the function call

```
foo('a' + (char) 5);
```

has type `int`.
To call the overloaded function with parameter of type char you have to write for example

```
foo( char( 'a' + 5 ) );
```

or

```
foo( ( char )( 'a' + 5 ) );
```

or you can use C++ casting like

```
foo( static_cast<char>( 'a' + 5 ) );
```

The above quotes from the C++ Standard also are valid for C Standard. The visible difference is that in C++ character literals have type `char` while in C they have type `int`.

So in C++ the output of the statement

```
std::cout << sizeof( 'a' ) << std::endl;
```

will be equal to 1.

While in C the output of the statement

```
printf( "%zu\n", sizeof( 'a' ) );
```

will be equal to `sizeof( int )` that is usually equal to 4.

Comment: @Dieter Lücking It depends on what working draft you refer to.

Comment: Please add the version to your answer